# Lazy Loaded component is not rendering Angular 4

Tags: angular, lazy-loading

I have implemented lazy loading module with angular 4 and able to create chuck successfully however when I try to render that lazy loaded module I am getting chuck successfully as I can see in my network and images are as below but component is not rendering and worst case is angular doesn't throw any error.

Please help me out If I am missing something.

app.routing.ts

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'career-info', loadChildren: 'app/components/career-info/career-info.module#CareerInfoModule', data: { pageName: 'career-info', screenName: 'experience level', screenCategory: 'choose template', title: 'Career Info - My Perfect Cover Letter', isRegisteredUser: true } },
  { path: 'how-it-works', component: HowItWorksComponent, data: { pageName: 'how-it-works', screenName: 'how it works', screenCategory: 'choose template', title: 'How It Works - My Perfect Cover Letter' } },
  { path: '**', loadChildren: 'app/components/career-info/career-info.module#CareerInfoModule' } // TODO: give here 404 component
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})

export class AppRoutingModule { }
export const RoutingComponents = [HowItWorksComponent]
```

Chunk
[image]

Network
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use **RouterModule.forChild(routes)** this will work.

Comment: After changing so I am getting error as "Unhandled Promise rejection: No provider for Router! ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: Error: No provider for Router!".

Comment: I don't know whether this is answer or not but route of lazy loaded module should be something like const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '', children: [
            { path: '', component: CareerInfoComponent },
            { path: 'career-info', component: CareerInfoComponent }
        ]
    },
];     as it is working for me.